# The second time I run setTimeout, it does not make my shape appear like it did the first time

Tags: javascript

The shape is supposed to appear after 1 second and start a timer. The shape is supposed to disappear on click and end the timer and display the reaction speed.

After another second, the shape is supposed to reappear and start the timer again. This is where the code is not working. On click, the shape is supposed to disappear, and end the timer, and display the reaction time.

```
<head>
    
 
        <title>Javascript</title>
        
        <style type="text/css">
            
            #shape{
                
                width:200px;
                height:200px;
                background-color: red;
                position:relative;
                visibility : hidden;
                
            }
        
        </style>
    
    </head>
 
    <body>
        
        
        <p id="Reactionline">Reaction time: <span id="reactionadded"></span></p>
        
        <hr style="margin-bottom: 5px; display:none;">
        
        <div id="shape"></div>
        
        
        <script>
            var start = new Date().getTime();
            
            function makeShapeAppear() {
                
                document.getElementById("shape").style.visibility = "visible";
                
                start= new Date().getTime();
                
            }
            
            
            function makeShapeDisappear() {
                document.getElementById('shape').onclick = function(){
                
                    document.getElementById('shape').style.visibility="hidden";
                    var end = new Date().getTime();
                    var time = (end - start)/1000 + " seconds";
                    document.getElementById("reactionadded").innerHTML= time;
                
                }
            }
                       
            setTimeout(makeShapeAppear, 1000);
            makeShapeDisappear(); 
            setTimeout(makeShapeAppear, 1000);      
            makeShapeDisappear(); 
        </script>
        
        
    </body>
```

Comment: Both timers expire at the same time... Note that `setTimeout` does not stop the execution of the rest of your code.

Answer (score 0):

```html
    <head>
    
 
        <title>Javascript</title>
        
        <style type="text/css">
            
            #shape{
                
                width:200px;
                height:200px;
                background-color: red;
                position:relative;
                visibility : hidden;
                
            }
        
        </style>
    
    </head>
 
    <body>
        
        
        <p id="Reactionline">Reaction time: <span id="reactionadded"></span></p>
        
        <hr style="margin-bottom: 5px; display:none;">
        
        <div id="shape"></div>
        
        
        <script>
            var start = new Date().getTime();
            
            function makeShapeAppear() {
                
                document.getElementById("shape").style.visibility = "visible";
                
                start= new Date().getTime();
                
            }
            
            
            function makeShapeDisappear() {
                document.getElementById('shape').onclick = function(){
                
                    document.getElementById('shape').style.visibility="hidden";
                    var end = new Date().getTime();
                    var time = (end - start)/1000 + " seconds";
                    document.getElementById("reactionadded").innerHTML= time;
                  
                  
                    setTimeout(makeShapeAppear, 1000);      
                    makeShapeDisappear(); 
                
                }
            }
                       
            setTimeout(makeShapeAppear, 1000);
            makeShapeDisappear(); 
        </script>
        
        
    </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should put the **`setTimeout(makeShapeAppear,1000)`** method in the **`makeShapeDisappear()`** function.

Answer (score 0):

You are going in right direction but your approach to the code is wrong. Here is one correct way of acheiving what you want to do. Run the Code Snippet below

```js
let start = new Date().getTime();

document.getElementById('shape').onclick = function() {
  document.getElementById('shape').style.visibility = "hidden";
  var end = new Date().getTime();
  var time = (end - start) / 1000 + " seconds";
  document.getElementById("reactionadded").innerHTML = time;
  makeShapeAppear();
}

function makeShapeAppear() {
  setTimeout(()=>{
   document.getElementById("shape").style.visibility = "visible";

  start = new Date().getTime();
  
  },1000);
}

makeShapeAppear();
```

```css
#shape {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
  position: relative;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<p id="Reactionline">
  Reaction time: <span id="reactionadded"></span>
</p>

<hr style="margin-bottom: 5px; display:none;">

<div id="shape"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var start = new Date().getTime();
    setTimeout(()=>{e.style.visibility="visible"}, 1000);
document.getElementById("shape").addEventListener('click',(e)=>{       
        e.style.visibility="hidden";
        var end = new Date().getTime();
        var time = (end - start)/1000 + " seconds";
        document.getElementById("reactionadded").innerHTML= time;
        setTimeout(()=>{e.style.visibility="visible"}, 1000);
  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

makeShapeDisappear sets the onclick of the button, so there's no need to call it twice, the on click callback should be invoked every time the button is clicked.

just add

```
setTimeout(makeShapeAppear, 1000);
```

in the click code so it reappears after you make it disappear..
and call it once outside to make it appear to begin with..

since you used settimeout as if it "waits" - ill just mention you could make setTimeout awaitable by doing something like this:

```
async function wait(ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(resolve, ms);
  });
}
```

and then you could call

```
await wait(1000);
```

when you want the entire code to "wait" a second..
although you wouldnt need that in this case